# Email Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with an email script that I found online. The script that I found worked if you are wanting to email everyone in column B. I created a section in column A asking if I want to email that individual person (because I am not going to want to email everyone) but I'm not sure on how to change the coding to recognize that. I am still trying to learn/understand JavaScript. Any help would be great.
Thanks.

You can view my sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-lcCUN7ROBAhWNFsqura5M7LvhsQnzBBqE06jxxQkFM/edit?usp=sharing

```
    function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1,5);   // Fetch the range of cells E1:E1
   var CC = range.getValues();
   var range = sheet.getRange(2,5);  // Fetch the range of cells E2:E2
   var subject = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for subject line from above range
   var range = sheet.getRange(2, 9);  // Fetch the range of cells I2:I2
   var numRows = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for number of emails from above range
   var startRow = 5;                  // First row of data to process
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows,8 ) // Fetch the range of cells B5:I_
   var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
   for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var emailAddress = row[0];      // 1st column
      var message = row[7];           // 8th column
       MailApp.sendEmail({
         to: emailAddress,
         cc: CC,
         subject: subject,
         htmlBody: message,

       })}
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the code what you are working with.

Comment: KRR, I've uploaded the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below:

```
  function sendEmails() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var range = sheet.getRange(1,5);   // Fetch the range of cells E1:E1
   var CC = range.getValues();
  var ccEmail = CC[0][0];
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,5);  // Fetch the range of cells E2:E2
   var subject = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for subject line from above range
    var emailSubject = subject[0][0];
   var range = sheet.getRange(2, 9);  // Fetch the range of cells I2:I2
   var numRows = range.getValues();   // Fetch value for number of emails from above range
   var startRow = 5;                  // First row of data to process
    var endRow = numRows[0][0];
   var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, endRow,8 ) // Fetch the range of cells B5:I_
   var data = dataRange.getValues();  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.

   for (i in data) {
      var row = data[i];
      var sendEmail = row[0];
      if (sendEmail == "Yes"){
        var emailAddress = row[1];      // 2nd column
        var message = row[7];           // 8th column
        MailApp.sendEmail({  to: emailAddress,   cc: ccEmail , subject: emailSubject, htmlBody: message});

      }
}
}
```

Edited the code as the getRange() method gets the values in a two dimensional array you have to get the first value from the arrays.
Hope that helps!

Comment: KRR, I tried your code and it work without any errors bit didn't send any emails out. I did a debug and noticed that some things were not lining up like the "send email" and "email address" so I corrected them and then it gave me an error about invalid email. Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure you are testing with a valid email addresses.

Comment: I've added my personal email and my school email and it's saying both are invalid emails.

Comment: That did the trick. I will look over your coding so that I can better understand what is going on.

Thanks.